# How do I dynamically iterate through a subquery

Tags: apex, loop

This is the server-side code for a lightning component. Normally I would return the last line, but its commented out here to test using anon execution

I think I am calling the parent Id in the loop and not the child Id.  How can I get the child Id returned from the query dynamically?

```
// I will pass in the sObj and rID (record ID).  Specifying here to test.
String[] sObj = new String[]{'Test__c'};
String[] rID = new String[]{'a0cr0000000LhhmAAC'};
// Array to pass back to return statement
Set<Id> docIDs = new Set<Id>();
// Make the describe call
Schema.DescribeSobjectResult[] results = Schema.describeSObjects(sObj);
// Loop through the describe
for(Schema.DescribeSobjectResult res : results) {
    // Holds generated queries
    List<String> subqueries = new List<String>();
    String query ='';
    // Get child relationships
    Schema.ChildRelationship[] rels = res.getChildRelationships();
    if (rels.size() > 0) {
        //System.debug(res.getName() + ' has ' + rels.size() + ' child relationships.');
        integer i = 1;
        for(Schema.ChildRelationship rel:rels){
            if (rel.getChildSObject().getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('Name') != null) {
        // I only care if the relationship is a custom object
                if(rel.getChildSObject().getDescribe().isCustom()) {
            // Get relationship name and field
                    SObjectType childType = rel.getChildSObject();
                    SObjectField lookupField = rel.getField();
            // build the query or subquery
                    subqueries.add('(SELECT Id FROM ' + rel.getRelationshipName() + ')');
                    query = 'SELECT ' + String.join(subQueries, ',') + ' FROM '+ sObj[0] + ' where Id = \'' + rId[0] + '\'' ;
            // Run the query with subqueries
                    List<SObject> ids = Database.query(query);
                    System.debug('Size: ' + ids.size() + ' - ' + query);
            // I think this is where its wrong, try to loop through the query
                    for(SObject idList:ids){
            // only returns the parent id
                        System.debug(idList.Id);
            // only queries the parent id.  I think I am using the wrong field for id.  I need the id returned from the children
                        List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl = [select id,contentdocumentid,contentdocument.Title from contentdocumentlink where linkedentityid = :idList.Id];
                        for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:cdl) {
                            docIDs.add (cdLink.ContentDocumentID);
                        }
                // The following 4 lines would be removed, and I would use the return statement at the end.  Leaving it here for testing
                                List<ContentDocument> q2ids = [Select id, title,fileextension from contentdocument where id in :docIDs];
                                for(ContentDocument cdLink2:q2ids) {
                                    System.debug(cdLink2.Title);
                                }
                    }
                    i++;
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
// Would normally use this line instead of the 4 above
//return [Select id, title,fileextension from contentdocument where id IN :docIDs];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I am understanding, I think you want all the `ContentDocuments` that are related to the parent and all its child records.

If that is the case, then yes, you are right when you say you are iterating over only the parent records and not traversing to the child records to get child Ids.

To do so, you probably have to make minor changes in your code

- Store all the `child relationship names` in a `Set`, so that it can be used later to get child records.
- Loop through the `Set` that is created in the previous step and get all the `child records Ids` using `getSObjects(fieldName)` method of [`SObject`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_getSObjects) class and add it in a `set` that can be used to query on `ContentDocumentLink`.
- Use this updated `Set` to query on `ContentDocumentLink`.

So pseudo code should be something like this

```
Set<string> setChildRelationshipNames = new Set<string>();
Set<Id> setAllIds = new Set<Id>();
//this will give all the child relationship names of that object, this you will need to do when you are building the SOQL query
setChildRelationshipNames.add(rel.getRelationshipName());

//now when iterating through the parent records, get all its child record Ids along with parent Ids in a single set
for(SObject idList:ids){
    setAllIds.add((Id)idList.get('Id'));
    for(string childRelationShipName : setChildRelationshipNames){
        List<sObject> childRecords = idList.getSObjects(childRelationShipName);
        for(sObject childRec : childRecords){
            setAllIds.add((Id)childRec.get('Id'));
        }
    }
}

//finally query on ContentDocumentLink to get all contentdocumentlinks which are related to a parent along with its child records
List<ContentDocumentLink> cdl = [select id,contentdocumentid,contentdocument.Title from contentdocumentlink where linkedentityid IN :setAllIds];
for(ContentDocumentLink cdLink:cdl) {
    docIDs.add (cdLink.ContentDocumentID);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vijay that did it !

Comment: That's great !!